# Create Weak Multimap with Google Collections

Tags: java, weak-references, guava, multimap

Is there an equivalent to the nice MapMaker for MultiMaps? 
currently i create the cache like this:

```
    public static Map<Session,List<Person>> personCache = new MapMaker().weakKeys().makeMap();
```

the whole point of MultiMap is to avoid the nested List Values. is there any way to construct the multimap with weak keys?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately not.  Yet.  Could you file a MultimapMaker feature request in our issues db?
http://google-collections.googlecode.com

Comment: Looks like it won't be worked on https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=142