# Cache or MultiMap for day-based cache expiration?

Tags: java, caching, guava, multimap

Context: I'm working on an analytics system for an ordering system. There are about 100,000 orders per day and the analytics need to run for the last N (say, 100) days months. The relevant data fits in memory. After N days, all orders are evicted from the memory cache,  with an entire day in the past being evicted. Orders can be created or updated.

1. A traditional approach would use a `ConcurrentHashMap<Date, Queue<Order>>`. Every day, values for keys representing dates more than N days in the past will be deleted. But, of course, the whole point of using Guava is to avoid this. EDIT: changed `Map` to `ConcurrentHashMap`, see the end of the question for rationale.
2. With Guava collections, a `MultiMap <Date, Order>` would be simpler. Eviction is similar, implemented explicitly.
3. While the `Cache` implementation looks appealing (after all, I am implementing a Cache), I'm not sure about the eviction options. Eviction only happens once a day and its best initiated from outside the cache, I don't want the cache to have to check the age of an order. I'm not even sure if the cache would use a MultiMap, which I think it's a suitable data structure in this case.

Thus, my question is: is it possible to use a Cache that uses and exposes the semantics of a MultiMap and allows evictions controlled from outside itself, in particular with the rule I need ("delete all orders older than N days") ?

As an important clarification, I'm not interested in a `LoadingCache` but I do need bulk loads (if the application needs to be restarted, the cache has to be populated, from the database, with the last N days of orders).

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the map *needs to be concurrent*, as orders come in they are evaluated live against the previous orders for the same customer or location etc.

EDIT2: Just stumbled over [Guava issue 135](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=135). It looks like the MultiMap is not concurrent.

Comment: See [Guava issue #142](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=142) (`Cache` is successor of `ConcurrentMap` produced by `MapMaker`) and also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737060/create-weak-multimap-with-google-collections).

Comment: And about edit#2: you can use [`Multimaps#synchronizedMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#synchronizedMultimap(com.google.common.collect.Multimap)) to have _a synchronized (thread-safe) multimap backed by the specified multimap_.

Comment: @Xaerxess Thanks, I'll have to test how it performs; I have some concerns it's not going to be as good as ConcurrentHashMap, in which case I'll have to go back to using the JDK classes (i.e. approach #1 in the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use neither a `Cache` nor a `Multimap` here. While I like and use both of them, there's not much to gain here.

- You want to evict your entries manually, so the features of `Cache` don't really get used here.
- You're considering `ConcurrentHashMap<Date, Queue<Order>>`, which is in a sense more powerful than a `Multimap<Date, Order>`.

I'd use a `Cache`, if I thought about different eviction criteria and if I felt like losing any of its entries anytime<sup>1</sup> is fine.

You may find out that you need a `ConcurrentMap<Date, Dequeue<Order>>` or maybe `ConcurrentMap<Date, YouOwnQueueFastSearchList<Order>>` or whatever. This could probably be managed somehow by the `Multimap`, but IMHO it gets more complicated instead of simpler.

I'd ask myself "what do I gain by using `Cache` or `Multimap` here?". To me it looks like the plain old `ConcurrentMap` offers about everything you need.

---

<sup>1</sup> By no means I'm suggesting this would happen with Guava. On the opposite, without an eviction reason (capacity, expiration, ...) it works just like a `ConcurrentMap`. It's just that what you've described feels more like a `Map` rather than a `Cache`.

Comment: I think you're right; earlier I saw this comment "Note: If you do not need the features of a Cache, ConcurrentHashMap is more memory-efficient -- but it is extremely difficult or impossible to duplicate most Cache features with any old ConcurrentMap." in http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained and while a Cache can return a ConcurrentMap, I think it's not worth using it.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO The simplest thing to do is to include the date of the order in the order record. (I would expect it is a field already)  As you only need to clean the cache once per day it doesn't have to be very efficient, just reasonably timely.

e.g.

```
public class Main {
    static class Order {
        final long time;

        Order(long time) {
            this.time = time;
        }

        public long getTime() {
            return time;
        }
    }

    final Map<String, Order> orders = new LinkedHashMap<String, Order>();

    public void expireOrdersOlderThan(long dateTime) {
        for (Iterator<Order> iter = orders.values().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
            if (iter.next().getTime() < dateTime)
                iter.remove();
    }

    private void generateOrders() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 120000; i++) {
            orders.put("order-" + i, new Order(i));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        for (int t = 0; t < 3; t++) {
            Main m = new Main();
            m.generateOrders();
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                m.expireOrdersOlderThan(i * 1000);
            long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
            System.out.printf("Took an average of %.3f ms to expire 1%% of entries%n", time / 20 / 1e6);
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
Took an average of 9.164 ms to expire 1% of entries
Took an average of 8.345 ms to expire 1% of entries
Took an average of 7.812 ms to expire 1% of entries
```

For 100,000 orders, I would expect this to take ~10 ms which is not so much to incur at a quiet period in the middle of the night.

BTW: You can make this more efficient if your OrderIds are sorted by time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a sorted list of some sort? It would allow you to pull entries until you hit one that's fresh enough to stay. Of course this assumes that's your primary functio. If what you most need is the O(1) access with a hashmap, my answer doesn't apply.

Comment: The order date is the key so in approach #1, the entire collection of orders (stored in a Queue) is evicted. But the question is more about #2 vs #3.